# what does the "Index: 68, Size: 10" means?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 68, Size: 10
```

I know what this errors means.. That I try to read a position of an array where it doesn't exists. I don't know however `this Index: 68, Size: 10` what does it means.. that I tried to read the position 68 of an array that has only 10 positions?

Answer (score 1):

> what does it means.. that I tried to read the position 68 of an array that has only 10 positions?

Exactly! `Index = 9` is the maximal index you can access.